# Copper sulphate, Benedict's Reagent and albumin

Tags: organic-chemistry, solutions

When my student's add Benedict's Reagent to albumin and heat it, the solution turns purple (as if testing for proteins).  Is it possible that the copper sulphate in the Benedict's is reacting with the protein in the albumin?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's most likely the same reaction as in the [Biuret test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biuret_test) that detects peptide bonds.

Comment: Suggest above *comment* be moved to *answer*.